# Remove everything after the first hyphen from the left

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to remove everything after third - from the left of a string including the -

Example My string has

INPUT:         sukumar-123-656-321-421

Output;                     sukumar-123

Requirement is to always remove everything from the last 3 hyphen - left of the string.

Comment: So can you please share what you have been trying and explain where you got stuck?

Comment: Is the length of the string always the same? Is the numbers after the hyphen always the same?

Comment: @murugan_bala just know that what you have asked for from the title of the question is different to what you have asked from the body of the question. You should pick one. Is it that you want to `remove everything from after the first hyphen` or you want to `remove everything after the third hyphen`. If you want both then you should state that explicitly.

Comment: It would be a good idea to define exactly how the output should look like for the following strings.1) Input=sukumar-123 expected_output=? 2)input=sukumar expected_output=? 3)Input=sukumar-123-656 expected_output=?. In the example you have shown the Input=sukumar-123-656-321-421, the 3rd hyphen position is "-321-421" however your expected output=sukumar-123 and not sukumar-123-656 ("remove everything after third "-")

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph - Can you make your commnet bold and tag goodvibration, so they can understand what I was trying to say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using regexes: the pattern `(-[^-]*)` matches a hyphen followed by any number of non-hyphen characters, the `{3}` makes it match three times in a row, and `$` makes it only match at the end of the string.

```py
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile('(-[^-]*){3}$')
>>> pattern.sub('', 'sukumar-123-656-321-421')
'sukumar-123'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
def func(x):
    return '-'.join(x.split('-')[:-3])
```